# How can I validate the messages sent by AWS SNS usign Spring Cloud SNS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

We are trying to receive notifications from AWS SNS service and we decided to use Spring Cloud SNS library to handle the request from AWS SNS.   [Here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-aws-messaging) is a sample of Spring Cloud SNS library.

Everything works fine, but we don't know how or where to validate the message like Amazon AWS documentation said.   There is a sample in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.example.java.html) however adding this validation using Spring Cloud SNS is where we get lost.

As an example, I would like to add this validation code before the message reaches the methods: confirmUnsubscribeMessage,receiveNotification and confirmSubscriptionMessage.

```
private static boolean isMessageSignatureValid(Message msg) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(msg.getSigningCertURL());
    InputStream inStream = url.openStream();
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
    inStream.close();

    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    sig.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());
    sig.update(getMessageBytesToSign(msg));
    return sig.verify(Base64.decodeBase64(msg.getSignature()));
    }
catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SecurityException("Verify method failed.", e);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which part don't you understand? Perhaps you could attach that sample directly on your question.

Comment: Hi due, Did you find the answer? Could you share the solution?